# Resize Image on button

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am creating an app in Xamarin Forms and try to imitate a `FloatingActionButton`, so I created a round `Button` that shall have a centered icon. Unfortunately my icon overlaps the `Button` by far and I have not found any way to properly rescale it. I tried to work around by making the `Button` that big so it fits to the icon and scale the whole thing down, but it loses it’s quality by that. Is there a way to only resize the image?

The `Button` could simply look like this, the problem seems to be something general:

```
<Button x:Name="button" ImageSource="image.png" />
```

Comment: How to rescale image ?

Comment: @ChetanRawat how to rescale image that is set to a button, yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 scenarios.

### If your image is not rounded and transparent

You can force it this way using a `Frame`:

```
<Frame CornerRadius="50" 
       HeightRequest="100"
       WidthRequest="100"
       Padding="0"
       IsClippedToBounds="True">
    <Image Source="image.png" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="MyTappedEvent" />
                <!-- or <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding MyCommand}" /> -->
            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
    </Image>
</Frame>
```

Just replace `HeightRequest`, `WidthRequest` and `CornerRadius` with your values. You have to make sure that `CornerRadius` is half the size or `WirthRequest`/`HeightRequest` to make it looks like a circle.

Then just use the `Tapped` event for basic usage or the `Command` of the `TapGestureRecognizer` if you use MVVM pattern.

---

### If your `png` image is already rounded and transparent

Then you can just use the TapGestureRecognizer directly on your image so it behaves like a button:

```
<Image Source="image.png" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100">
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding AddCommand}" />
    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
```

Hope it helps,

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer and your help, it works perfectly for me!